# mongoosejs pre save hook on array field

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I want to have all the category lower case
I tried this:

```
ArticleSchema.pre('save', function(next) {

    _.map(this.categories, function(category) { 
        console.log(category.toLowerCase());
        return category.toLowerCase();  
    });    
    next();
});
```

but it doesn't work (If I insert ie PHP,JAVA I find PHP,JAVA)

What's wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map()` doesn't modify the original array, you need to assign the result to the property:

```
ArticleSchema.pre('save', function(next) {

    this.categories = _.map(this.categories, function(category) { 
        console.log(category.toLowerCase());
        return category.toLowerCase();  
    });    
    next();
});
```